# Docx4j Human captcha

Tags: captcha

I'm trying to register on a forum (http://www.docx4java.org/forum) but i don't know the Human captcha :S

The question is:

"Think of the names of popular Java IDEs. Tell me a part of human anatomy which is a substring of an IDE name."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, after this long, that you failed the Turing test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, 'lips' is a substring of Eclipse.  And 'foot' is a substring of Greenfoot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you are looking at lips. From Eclipse.